# How to ignore brackets, commas and fullstops when reading a text file in java?

Tags: java, readfile

I have a text file that has two paragraphs. it has periods and comas at the end of some words and when I read the file those comas are also added to the list of words read.
this is the code that read the file

```
public static Scanner openTextFile(String fileName) {
    Scanner data;

    try{
        data = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        return data;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(fileName  + " did not read correctly");
    }  
    data = null;
    return data;
}
```

But I want it to read only the words and ignore any commas or periods or any brackets next to it.
How can I achieve it

i used replaceall method but it didnt work at all

```
public static void readOtherFile(Scanner data, int g[][], Key[] hashTable, int[] keyWordCounter, int modValue)  {
    int lineCounter = 0, wordCounter = 0;
    
    String x;
    String []y;
    while(data.hasNextLine()){
        lineCounter += 1;  
        x = data.nextLine();
        
        /*the following conditional statement takes care of the issue of their being an
         * entirely blank line encountered before reaching the end of the text file.
         */
        if(x.length() == 0) {
            x = data.nextLine();
        }
        
        x = x.toLowerCase();
        x = x.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
      
        
        y = x.split(" ");
        wordCounter +=  y.length;
        
        //method compares a token to a key word to see if they are identical.
        checkForKeyWord(y, g, hashTable, keyWordCounter, modValue);
    }
    //method prints statistical results
    printResults(lineCounter, wordCounter, hashTable, keyWordCounter);
}
```

Sample file
[sample file link](https://usaupload.com/file/4SU4/tstOdd.txt)

Comment: Show sample file.

Comment: i got the answer and program is working. anyhow i added the sample file for anyone with the same probelm will get help from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you can use a regular expression on the data you parse from your file as a string. You need to return the data you read from the first before you do string manipulation. Its bad practice to do the string manipulation within the while-loop.

```
  static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
  throws IOException
   {
     byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
     return new String(encoded, encoding);
   }

  String data = d.replaceAll("[,.]", "");
```

Comment: this worked for me. before i used `replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");` didnt work

Comment: @AMohamedSakeel You need to return the data you read from the first before you do string manipulation. Its bad practice to do the string manipulation within the while-loop.

Comment: yeah but its a void

Comment: @AMohamedSakeel Try this: replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_-]]+", "");